# Cloud Storage services, what, how and which?

Tags: ios, database, cloud, storage, google-cloud-storage

In some ways I guess you could say I'm creating something similar to the iOS app 'Vine'. A social network letting users upload videos for others to watch. My entire project is pretty much ready, I'm using a database service called [Parse](http://www.parse.com), but there's not much storage there, and if you want to scale it up, it gets pricey. I have figured I can use the database I already have, and having the sql-table for "Videos" have an URL-column linking to the actual video file. I have been looking for data storage services, and found Google's 'Cloud Storage'.

What I'm really looking for, if possible, is something like this use case:

1. Client app has a video ready to upload.
2. Uploads video-file to `some-cloud-service.com/myCompany/videoNameID.mp4`
3. Store this URL in the URL-field of a 'video-object' in the database.
4. When other users are fetching a list of videos, they get a collection of names and URLs
5. When the user wants to play a certain video, fetch it from the URL in the table.

I have been thinking I can use cloud storage as a place to upload and access files for my app. I've been looking through the API and documentation for Google's Cloud Storage, but there's so much in there I have no use for, and I don't understand most of it. I'm starting to think "Cloud Storage" isn't what I think it is. I simply need a place to upload potentially huge amounts of large files, directly from an iOS-app (and website later). The data storage service Parse offers is perfect, but very limited in size. I know it has the potential of getting expensive. From reading the prices of [this](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/cloud-storage) google service, it looked both cheap and exactly what I need, but I can't understand how, if possible, I should use it to directly upload a file using my "credentials", and receiving an URL in return for where the file ended up.

Can I use Google's Cloud Storage for this? Or something else? Or have I completely misunderstood how to use Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the Objective-C wrapper library for the Google services has quite detailed documentation here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Preparing_to_Use_the_Library

It tells you that this wrapper library is generated automatically based on the underlying JSON APIs. So all the GTLStorage... classes will mimic the JSON API for Google Storage. The class for performing the actual API calls is GTLQueryStorage.

If you look at that JSON documentation, you'll find that there is a class Objects that is used to store data into buckets: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/#Objects
The method to upload a new object is 'insert'

Back at the GTLQueryStorage.h file, you'll find the corresponding Objective-C method to insert a new object into your bucket:

```
// Method: storage.objects.insert
// Stores new data blobs and associated metadata.
//  Required:
//   bucket: Name of the bucket in which to store the new object. Overrides the
//     provided object metadata's bucket value, if any.
//  Optional:
//   ifGenerationMatch: Makes the operation conditional on whether the object's
//     current generation matches the given value.
//   ifGenerationNotMatch: Makes the operation conditional on whether the
//     object's current generation does not match the given value.
//   ifMetagenerationMatch: Makes the operation conditional on whether the
//     object's current metageneration matches the given value.
//   ifMetagenerationNotMatch: Makes the operation conditional on whether the 
//     object's current metageneration does not match the given value.
//   name: Name of the object. Required when the object metadata is not
//     otherwise provided. Overrides the object metadata's name value, if any.
//   projection: Set of properties to return. Defaults to noAcl, unless the
//     object resource specifies the acl property, when it defaults to full.
//      kGTLStorageProjectionFull: Include all properties.
//      kGTLStorageProjectionNoAcl: Omit the acl property.
//  Upload Parameters:
//   Accepted MIME type(s): */*
//  Authorization scope(s):
//   kGTLAuthScopeStorageDevstorageFullControl
//   kGTLAuthScopeStorageDevstorageReadWrite
// Fetches a GTLStorageObject.
+ (id)queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:(GTLStorageObject *)object
                           bucket:(NSString *)bucket
                 uploadParameters:(GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersOrNil;
```

So you should:

- Allocate an instance of GTLServiceStorage
- Set your API key to that object
- Instantiate a GTLQueryStorage object using the class method above for the object you want to save with the right bucket
- Create a Service Ticket which performs the query and gets a completion handler to handle the completion (success, error cases).

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to understand the examples now. Right now I'm trying to upload a file I have saved on a URL in my device, but I can't figure out how to make a `GTLStorageObject` of it. Every search for GTLStorageObject just leads to the extremely tiny header-file, there's simply no information out there. I bet I'm just about to figure out how easy it really is to instantiate a GTLStorageObject, but I'll ask you just in case I won't, do you know where I should look for this?

Comment: As it turns out, I have no idea how to instantiate it.. Isn't the method asking for the object to upload when it says `..insertWithObject:(GTLStorageObject*)object..`? And that would mean I have to cast or convert my file, in my case I have the url to a local .mp4-video, into a GTLStorageObject? In the examples they are using `GTLDriveFile` which is for Google Drive. I'll dive deeper into source codes to see if I find anything, but I'm amazed over the lack of documentation. Then again, I just noticed the whole JSON-part is 'experimental' and somehow beta. (None of the examples use cloud:/)

Comment: Hi Rheven, the GTLStorageObject only stores the metadata about the object. Actually, when you upload data, you only need to alloc/init this and pass it to the method query... which will then update the GTLStorageObject with all the metadata. You pass the actual file/data using GTLUploadParameters: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Objects/GTLUploadParameters.h

Comment: But.. There's no way to alloc/init a GTLStorageObject. I CAN alloc/init it as a GTLObject and cast it though, but I kinda feel like that defeats the purpose..?

Comment: GTLStorageObject is a subclass of GTLObject, so it inherits all its methods, including initialization. `GTLStorageObject *aStorageObject = [GTLStorageObject object];` will just give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Have you had any luck uploading to cloud storage personally? I tried this now, and get exceptions saying I'm "uploading to the wrong URL" when I never specified it was a resumable upload(even though that's what I actually want)

Comment: I haven't used the Storage Service. I've used the Drive service, and as far as I can see it works quite similar (except for Drive service you need a user to log in to access his Drive). I'd suggest you look at the sample code for Drive: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m, specifically the code for `-(void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString*)path` on line 620

Comment: @Rheven are you tied to Google as Cloud storage provider? I've found that there aren't yet that many other developers that have developed simple wrappers for their APIs, so you're pretty much on your own. For cloud storage, have you considered Amazon S3? They have a sample iOS project specifically for that (uploading photos to S3): http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS/3002109349624271

Comment: It's quite similar, but at the same time, not completely. For instance, I'm not able to give my GTLStorageObject a `.title`, in fact I'm not able to give it anything at all. It has 3 class methods, and that's it, I have no idea how or if I should use them. In the documentation for JSON-upload in storage: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable it says that I have to send an initial 'empty' request, and receive an URI, and then specify THIS URI as the destination. It's not documented in the obj-c though, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not tied, no, and I did look around Amazons website, but there were so many people complaining over the upload and download speed of S3 being incredibly slow, like kilobytes, and I can just prematurely feel the feeling I'll sit here with if I ditch Google for Amazon now and Google later blooms with this Google Cloud McAwesomeSpeed.

Comment: haha, yes that's true. Upload speed won't be so much an issue as most internet connections don't have such high upload speeds anyway, but download will definitely be an issue. However, if you upload all your files to one bucket and setup CloudFront for that bucket, you can download using normal URL fetching, taking the CloudFront URL instead, which will be super fast.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll definitely try that. I also realized that the JSON API used by Google Cloud Storage for Obj-C still is in beta, or "experimental", so I wouldn't really be able to release my app when it's ready, I'd have to wait for Google to finish their thing(all URL's have /v1beta2/ in them).
Well, my original question is definitely answered though. I guess I'll try my luck with Google Cloud Storage later if I don't hit it off with Amazon. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your GTLStorageObject has a bunch of properties: So if you've created an instance `myStorageObject`, you can do `myStorageObject.name = @"filename"` and `myStorageObject.contentType = @"video/mp4"` etc... You don't need to do anything special for the whole resume thing. The iOS library always uses Google's resumable upload protocal. You can use the serviceTicket to monitor progress and pause and resume uploads: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Pause_and_Resume

Comment: One thing: Google has a lot of stuff in beta that is really usable in released products. They tend to keep things in 'beta' for years. It just means less garantees. But I think in this case Amazon is definitely more solid and you'll find more resources to help you.

Comment: No, that's the weird thing. I have opened the GTLStorageObject, and I saw all those properties, but I can't access any of them. I don't know if it's because they're `@dynamic` or what it is, but if I go `object.name=@"filename";` then I get `error:Property 'name' cannot be found in forward class object 'GTLStorageObject'`.
Hm.. Maybe there's a header I should import somewhere, that doesn't necessarily make an error for missing, but is still needed..?

Comment: Had to import `#import "GTLStorage"`  (  -________-  )
Still getting the same error though, so I'm guessing it has to be something about what the documentation was saying for Resumable Uploads. Meh. (I was just importing GTLStorageObject, GTLQueryStorage etc.)

Comment: Can i have this topic especially in swift?thanks..:)

Answer (score 1):

late response, but this may help others with this issue. this code uploads a video to GCS (tested and working)

### Authentication first

this will pop the Google authentication view controller (you have to add "GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib" file to your project).

```
- (void) uploadVideoToGoogleCloud {

// declare this
//@property (strong, nonatomic) GTLServiceStorage* serviceStorage;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* accessToken;

_serviceStorage = [[GTLServiceStorage alloc] init];
_serviceStorage = [GTLServiceStorage new];
_serviceStorage.additionalHTTPHeaders = @{@"x-goog-project-id": @"yourGoogleProjectId"};

// authenticate
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *oAuthVC =
[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeStorageDevstorageReadWrite
                                           clientID:@"yourClientId from Client ID for iOS application"
                                       clientSecret:@"yourSecret from Client ID for iOS application"
                                   keychainItemName:@"use nil or give a name to save in keychain"
                                  completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {

                                      _accessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [auth.parameters objectForKey:@"access_token"]];

                                      _serviceStorage.additionalHTTPHeaders = @{@"x-goog-project-id": kProjectID, @"Content-Type": @"application/json-rpc", @"Accept": @"application/json-rpc", @"Authorization": _accessToken};

                                      _serviceStorage.authorizer = auth;


                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                      });
                                  }];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:oAuthVC animated:YES completion:nil];
});
}
```

### Upload Video after authentication

after user has authenticated successfully, call this to upload the video

```
// upload video file
NSString *filename = @"yourVideoFileNameNoExtension";
NSString *pathToMovie = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@".mp4"];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:pathToMovie];
if (fileHandle) {

    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParam =
    [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle MIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    GTLStorageObject *storageObj = [GTLStorageObject object];
    storageObj.name = @"thisWillAppearOnTheBucketAsTheFilename";

    GTLQueryStorage *query = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:storageObj bucket:@"your-bucket-name" uploadParameters:uploadParam];

    GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [_serviceStorage executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error ? [error description] : @"query succeeded!");
    }];


    ticket.uploadProgressBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                   unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead,
                                   unsigned long long dataLength) {
        NSLog(@"ticket: %@", ticket);
        NSLog(@"read %llu from %llu bytes", numberOfBytesRead, dataLength);
    };

} else {
    NSLog(@"no video file handle!");
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Late response from me too! I ended up using Amazon's services, but I'm now considering to go for Google Cloud Storage after all. I see that their JSON-API finally is out of beta (as it was last time I checked, a year ago). However, in our application we have our own database handling users, we don't want our users to HAVE TO log in with their google-account to use it, so the first part of your answer doesn't really work for me. I've tried 'skipping' the step, but get "Login required" in return. Any way to allow uploads from ANYONE (who has a secret key (which is hardcoded in the app))?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cloud storage is for file upload. The terminology used by Parse is more simple than that used by Google. For Google you want to read [this document](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques), specifically the 'Implementing Resumable Uploads with the XML API' but read the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it, but by a first look, I see a lot of what they call "Examples" on how to upload a file etc, but I have no idea how to read it. It's not any code I recognize. You wouldn't happen to know of any guides or tutorials for using this Google API (for my intended use) with iOS? I was hoping it was as easy as the use case in my question, using something like `ASIHTTPRequest` to send a file to my cloud-"domain", and get the full url in return, and the file now being a publicly accessible url like www.something.com/me/video.mp4.

Comment: After reading some, and navigating back and forth in this madness of crappy documentation, I finally found this: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ it has given me a hell of a headache, but looks like what I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: To give you an idea what you're looking at, the document Wain linked to is describing exact HTTP messages. HTTP is the protocol that powers the web, and in fact you can use a normal web browser to make simple requests to Google Cloud Storage. GCS has two interfaces, one based on XML and one based on JSON. Many Google APIs use the same style of JSON interface, and the Objective-C library you've found is a wrapper for all of them. Accordingly, the documentation on the google cloud storage JSON API will provide you with the most help on what individual parameters are for.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Thanks, unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how exactly to use this library. No documentation at all. There is one example in there on how to upload files, but that's with Google Drive, and I need something with Cloud Storage. I figured I should use the 'service' "GTLStorage" from the example project, but all I can find about these classes are the classes themselves. I'm starting to think I might not need the API, just some way of uploading files to my 'bucket'. I have no idea how to do that from within Objective-C/iOS